# How to keep the state of the Material-UI AutoComplete when the component re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm using Material-UI v4 `AutoComplete` component with `renderOption` prop to render a `checkbox` item option, However the problem is when `onChange` event fires it updates a `hook` in the parent component and results a render to the child and thus the state of the component and the state of selected items are lost which leads to inconsistency in the UI and the logic, How can I prevent such scenario while rendering!

```
export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      onChange={(e, values)=> {
          setMoveisFilter(values); // it calls the setter of the hook at the parent component

      }}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Checkboxes"
          placeholder="Favorites"
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
    />
```

Comment: Please include the code where you're saving the selected item in state.

Answer (score 2):

https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/
getOptionSelected prop is what you're looking for
e.g getOptionSelected = (option, values) => option._id === values._id

Comment: Thank you so much! I was scratching my head as to why my pre-selected options coming from an API backend were not preselecting the pending options in autocomplete

Comment: This does not retain the state in the text field autocomplete box it just highlights the element in the listbox